# Playing 2 MediaPlayers at same time together playing only one MediaPlayer in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, multiple-instances

In my app I am playing `"Voice audio Mediaplayer"` and `"Background music MediaPlayer"`, It is working on below Android `lollipop 5.0` versions. But, when I was checking on `Lollipop and Android One os`, it was not playing 2 media players at same time. Only "Background Mediaplayer" is playing. But when I checked in `Debug mode` Voice mediaplayer was Playing.

This is my code for initializing mediaplayer

**In onCreate() :**

```
audioManger = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManger.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
audioManger = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// Intializing Voice audio Mediaplayer

voiceMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
voiceMediaPlayer.setDataSource(bagroundMusicAudioFileName);
voiceMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
voiceMediaPlayer.prepare();  

// Intializing Background music Mediaplayer

bgMusicMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
bgMusicMediaPlayer.setDataSource(bagroundMusicAudioFileName);
bgMusicMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
bgMusicMediaPlayer.prepare();
```

**Play button onClickListener() :**

```
// Starting Voice and Background MediaPlayers 

if(voiceMediaplayer == null) {
   voiceMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   voiceMediaPlayer.setDataSource(bagroundMusicAudioFileName);
   voiceMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
   voiceMediaPlayer.prepare();   
}
voiceMediaPlayer.start();

if(bgMusicMediaPlayer == null) {
   bgMusicMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   bgMusicMediaPlayer.setDataSource(bagroundMusicAudioFileName);
   bgMusicMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
   bgMusicMediaPlayer.prepare();     
}
bgMusicMediaPlayer.start();
```

**on Pause button onClickListener :**

// Stop Voice & Background mediaplayers on pause button click

```
if (voiceMediaPlayer != null && voiceMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    voiceMediaPlayer.reset();
    voiceMediaPlayer.release();
    voiceMediaPlayer = null;
}
if (bgMusicMediaPlayer != null && bgMusicMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    bgMusicMediaPlayer.reset();
    bgMusicMediaPlayer.release();
    bgMusicMediaPlayer = null;
}
```

When I am playing both meidaplayers at same time I am hearing only background music only on Moto-g(Lollipop os) device but this code is `working on below < 5.0(Lollipop) versions`. My mobile version is `4.4.4` kitkat it is working on my device.

Anything wrong in my code? How to play 2 MediaPlayers at a time in Lollipop?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution from [Playing multiple songs with MediaPlayer at the same time: only one is really playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379441/playing-multiple-songs-with-mediaplayer-at-the-same-time-only-one-is-really-pla)

Thank you guys you saved my time.